# jquery button active desactive state

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an issue with the following jQuery code:

I have 3 buttons, here is the code :

```
<button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" id="valider" data-actionname="appliquer" disabled>ok</button>

<button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" id="choisir" data-actionname="choose" disabled>choisir</button>

<button id="add" data-actionname="ajouteritems" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary">Ajouter</button>
```

and i want that when i click on ajouter item the button choisir become active and when i click on choisir the button ok become active here is my js code for now :

```
var boutton = function(bouton) {
    $('#add').click(function() {
        $('#choisir').removeAttr('disabled');
    });
}
```

thanks it's not reloading anymore but it won't activated the choisir button do you guy have any idea why ?is it understandable tell me if not 
thanks.

Comment: it is reloading the page because the default type of a button is submit, try to provide the `type="button"` attribute on add button

Comment: add a type to the buttons `[type="button"]`, default is `submit`.

Comment: And what when you click on `OK` button?

Comment: @BhushanKawadkar when you click on ok button it will be later a link to another page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can bind click event to `button` tag and active its previous button using below jquery :

```
$('button').click(function(){
   var $prevButton = $(this).prev('button');
   // check if previous button available
   if($prevButton.length > 0)
     $prevButton.removeAttr('disabled');
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kzhL2/3/)**

And put `type="button"` as chriz said

```
<button type = "button" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" id="valider" data-actionname="appliquer" disabled>ok</button>

<button type = "button" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" id="choisir" data-actionname="choose" disabled>choisir</button>

<button type = "button" id="add" data-actionname="ajouteritems" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary">Ajouter</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Reloading (caused by submit by the button) can be prevented by using `preventDefault()` on the event like this:

```
var boutton = function(bouton) {
    $('#add').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#choisir').removeAttr('disabled');
    });
}
```

[jQuery API reference event.preventDefault()](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/)

Answer (score 0):

add `type = button` to your button like below, because default type of button is `submit`

```
<button type = "button" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" id="valider" data-actionname="appliquer" disabled>ok</button>

<button type = "button" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" id="choisir" data-actionname="choose" disabled>choisir</button>

<button type = "button" id="add" data-actionname="ajouteritems" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary">Ajouter</button>
```

u need to call your function like `boutton();`

```
var boutton = function(bouton) {
    $('#add').click(function() {
        $('#choisir').removeAttr('disabled');
    });
}
boutton();
```

or simply use this code

```
 $('#add').click(function() {
        $('#choisir').removeAttr('disabled');
 });
```

Comment: thanks it's not reloading anymore but it won't activated the choisir button do you guy have any idea why ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is your solution:

```
var boutton = function(bouton) {
    $('#add').click(function(e) {
        $('#choisir').removeAttr('disabled');
        e.preventDefault();
    });
    $('#choisir').click(function(e) {
        $('#valider').removeAttr('disabled');
        e.preventDefault();
    });
}

boutton(); // You need this to initialize the function 
           // Otherwise, it will not work
```

And here is the **[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kzhL2/1/)**

Comment: thanks and i am doing it as an exposed method so like this return {bouton:bouton}

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 //by default am making the two buttons disbled(choisir & ok)
 $("#valider,#choisir").attr('disabled','disabled');
 //when clicking on the Ajouter 
   $("#add").click(function(){
       $("#choisir").removeAttr('disabled');    
     });
$("#choisir").click(function(){
    $("#valider").removeAttr('disabled');   
});
```

});

Answer (score 0):

if you have placed your buttons in a form then you can try with this:

```
var boutton = function(e, el) {
   if($(el).prop('id') === 'add'){
      $('#choisir').prop('disabled', false);
   }else if($(el).prop('id') === 'choisir'){
      $('#valider').prop('disabled', false);
   }
}

$('button').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    boutton(e, this);
});
```

#### [Fiddle in action](http://jsfiddle.net/5WU8A/)

Answer (score 0):

I guess need to put 'type="button"' on the button

```
<button type="button" yclass="btn btn-lg btn-primary" id="valider" data-actionname="appliquer" disabled>ok</button>


<button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" id="choisir" data-actionname="choose" disabled>choisir</button>


<button type="button" id="add" data-actionname="ajouteritems" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary">Ajouter</button>
```

JS:

```
$('#add').click(function() {
    $('#choisir').removeAttr('disabled');
});

$('#choisir').click(function() {
    $('#valider').removeAttr('disabled');
});
```

Here is the fiddle [sample](http://jsfiddle.net/8aGE6/)